# Change user image based on who's logged in

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm currently working on a login portal.

I already set the log in and log out functions and placed a session start button on every page.

My problem now is that I would like to update the user image based on the identity of who is logged in.

I'm using a template my boss chose, and this is the code where the image is:

```
<span>
    <img src="../../global/portraits/5.jpg" alt="...">
 </span>
```

Just a simple `<img>` tag with the link where the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPwm8.png) is.

My project is in an html file with php implemented, and I tried to do this in the `<span>` tag, instead of `<img>`:

```
<?php
        $W = ["Raffaella", "Milena", "Domiziana"];
        $M = ["Umberto", "Domenico"];
    
        if ($_SESSION["nome"] == $W) {
                echo '<img src="W.jpg">';
        } else if ($_SESSION["nome"] == $M){
                echo '<img src="M.jpg">';
        }
?>
```

where *$_SESSION["nome"]* represents the current user logged in. However, it doesn't do anything, not even producing an error.

Can someone explain how I can do it correctly, please? I'm new to php and trying to understand by studying alone on the internet

I was also considering JavaScript for this work (instead of PHP), but I don't know where to start

Comment: None of the usernames will equal the array. You need to use `in_array($_SESSION["nome"],  $W)`.  See: [in_array](https://www.php.net/in_array).

Comment: `$W` and `$M` are **arrays**, so a list is never going to match a single name. This is possibly producing a warning (check your PHP log, assuming you've got logging switched on). But why have you got two hard-coded lists of  users in two separate arrays to begin with? It doesn't make a lot of sense that way...don't you have them listed in a database, along with a the name of their associated image file? This kind of hard-coding is unsustainable once you have many users, and also naming the files by the first letter of their name is going to become a problem fairly quickly as well - use an ID.

Comment: P.S. using JS for this wouldn't make much sense - the session value is in PHP, and your user list is held server-side too, so dumping all that out to JS would be a waste of time and possibly also a security issue.

Comment: Further, since neither of the two conditions is matched, I'm wondering what is actually output. Are you sure that 1. you're adding this in the right place, and 2. your templates are parsed for PHP code?

Comment: I've got two list cause I divided them by sex, for the moment I'm using just two img.

Comment: I neww so i'm gonna ask maybe something stupid: should i add the img to my database? like for every user an img?

Comment: @MarkusAO i dont know how to answer either of your question. I'm walking in the dark for this thing i'm trying to do. Havent found nothing online that could help me

Comment: `I've got two list cause I divided them by sex`...why would you need to do that? A user is a user is a user, they're all the same. Having two lists just makes processing those users more complicated. If you need to know their sex at any given moment in your code, ask your database.

Comment: `should i add the img to my database`...no but for each user you should the _name_ of their image file, so you know which file is for each person.

Comment: @ADyson I found a way to have the session value in JS. I'm gonna post it on my answer

Comment: To see what's been actually output by your code, load the page in your browser, and then use the View Source feature, or the Element Inspector (inside the browser's Developer Tools) to see the raw code. Then you can see what was actually inside the `<span>` (if anything).

Comment: oh okay, I thought it's was a good way to do that but okay, gonna abandon that thinking ahha

Comment: @nana Having the session value in JS is a) a security issue and b) won't directly solve any of your problems. You still need to make it select the right image depending on the user's name. And for that you still need a valid list of users and something to associate each file to each user. and using JS will slow down your image loading into the page, and it's pointless.

Comment: Oh okau, sorry. I didnt know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like both $W and $M are array of names, rather than a single user, if that's the case, I assume you're trying to determine if a user is in that array. In PHP, you can use:

```
in_array($_SESSION["nome"], $W)
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

which will return true/false.

```
        if (true === in_array($_SESSION["nome"], $W)) {
                echo '<img src="W.jpg">';
        } else if (true === in_array($_SESSION["nome"], $M){
                echo '<img src="M.jpg">';
        }
```

But, this only gives two separate images for up to 5 unique names, and I'm not sure if that's what you're going for.

Comment: This actually did what i needed to do. Yes, i only wanted two img because the portal is at his first version and users have upload their image yet, so i needed a temporary img to use and decided to divided them by sex

Comment: @nana still better to design it with the final goal in mind, and then just associate the temporary images to each user as appropriate. In today's modern world though I'd avoid using sex/gender-specific stock images, personally. Just have a generic "user" icon for anyone who hasn't uploaded a photo. It avoids the potential for certain political difficulties. Just my opinion though, you are of course allowed to design it however you wish.

Comment: In the future, I would just name the images after the user, or some id to identify them by. That way, you can just 
```
echo '<img src="'. $_SESSION["nome"] .'.jpg">';
```

and no matter who logs in, as long as their profile pic has been created with a matching name, it will be identified. Of course, make sure you are using sanitized values.

And yes, i agree with @ADyson 100%, plan for your final result, when you can.